# How can I add a custom head and name on a mob with command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a zombie with my head(TheMiningTeam) and a visible name(TheMiningTeam) but I don't know how. If anyone can help me I will be really happy. If possible, can you add a light blue leather tunic, black leather pants and white leather boots?
This is what i tried:

> /summon Zombie 195 202 2 {CustomName:"TheMiningTeam",{ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:TheMiningTeam}}}]}

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual Problem is the opening `{` around `ArmorItems:[]`. Do away with that and it works.

```
/summon Zombie 195 202 2 {CustomName:"TheMiningTeam",ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:TheMiningTeam}}]}
```

you're missing `CustomNameVisible:1` to make the name always visible and not only when you're looking at the zombie (if you want that).

(you should probably use `id:"minecraft:skull"` instead)